# How to align text in the middle of \items?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, itemize

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Enfranchise
        \item Talisman
        \item Noxious : Abrasive
        \item Billowing : Replete
        \item Tangent : Abasement
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

What I would like is to align the words `Abrasive`, `Replete`, and `Abasement` only, without introducing any other additional spacing anywhere else (that `align` seems to do in between the new lines?)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want? Note the `eqparbox` package requires two compilations.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Enfranchise
        \item Talisman
        \item \eqmakebox[A][l]{Noxious :} Abrasive
        \item \eqmakebox[A][l]{Billowing :} Replete
        \item \eqmakebox[A][l]{Tangent :} Abasement
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `eqparbox` package is really helpful (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)! Never heard of it before. Great answer. I provided a manual solution which is clearly more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

> I use an invisible box with a specific width (`calc` package, `\widthof` command).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\section*{\textbackslash framebox}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Enfranchise
        \item Talisman
        \item \framebox[\widthof{Billowing:}][l]{Noxious:} Abrasive
        \item \framebox[\widthof{Billowing:}][l]{Billowing:} Replete
        \item \framebox[\widthof{Billowing:}][l]{Tangent:} Abasement
    \end{itemize}

\section*{\textbackslash makebox}    

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Enfranchise
        \item Talisman
        \item \makebox[\widthof{Billowing:}][l]{Noxious:} Abrasive
        \item \makebox[\widthof{Billowing:}][l]{Billowing:} Replete
        \item \makebox[\widthof{Billowing:}][l]{Tangent:} Abasement
    \end{itemize}    

\end{document}
```

[image]